# Нужно ли подгонять изображение в формате SVG для разных экранов?

Tags: android, svg, android-drawable

1. Это же векторная графика, такое изображение все равно нужно раскидывать по папкам xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi?
2. В студии стандартные папки созданы под форматы xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi и xxhdpi, а на офф сайте по андроиду в мануале указаны форматы xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi. Кому верить? какие все таки нужно иметь наборы размеров изображений?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Векторную графику не нужно делать под каждое разрешение, это актуально только для растровой графики и связано с тем, что при масштабировании растровой графики будут артефакты, так же слишком большие растровые изображения потребляют много ресурсов, что плохо для слабых устройств. Векторная графика лишена этих недостатков.

Все изображения векторной графики складываются в корневую папку *res/drawable/*, если только для каких то отдельных квалификаторов не требуется использовать другое изображение (например, на планшетах другую иконку)

PS: иметь нужно те "наборы" изображений, экраны каких устройств вы собираетесь поддерживать

Answer (score 3):

Насчёт второго вопроса, эта информация есть [на официальном сайте Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html).

Спецификаторы для ресурсов с разными форматами экрана по плотности пикселей:

- **ldpi** – low-density screens ~120dpi
- **mdpi** – medium-density screens ~160dpi
- **hdpi** – high-density screens ~240dpi
- **xhdpi** – extra-high-density screens ~320dpi
- **xxhdpi** – extra-extra-high-density screens ~480dpi
- **xxxhdpi** – extra-extra-extra-high-density screens ~640dpi

Также есть спецификатор для ресурсов независимых от характеристик экрана:

- **nodpi** – ресурсы для всех плотностей пикселей; система не масштабирует ресурсы с этим спецификатором.

---

Получается, оба источника верны. Просто те мануалы с **ldpi** староваты, раз ориентируются на маленькие экраны, в то время как студия ориентируется на крупные с **xxhdpi**.